# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'file.mp3'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame, mp3

The program runs only twice. Later, the error occurs. I don't know why it works twice and then stops.

```
import tkinter, sys, pygame
from tkinter import messagebox
from gtts import gTTS

soundfile="file.mp3"

def ex():
    sys.exit()
```

The main problem is there:

```
def read():
    t = e.get()
    tts = gTTS(text=t, lang="en")
    tts.save(soundfile)
    pygame.mixer.init(frequency=16000, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(soundfile)
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(1.0)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(0,0.0)
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()==True:
        continue
    pygame.quit()
```

Next is the code for the buttons.

```
def clear():
    e.delete(0, 'end')

main = tkinter.Tk()

e = tkinter.Entry(main, justify = "center")
l = tkinter.Label(main, text = "Write text")
b1 = tkinter.Button(main, text = "Read", command = read)
b2 = tkinter.Button(main, text = "Clear", command = clear)
b3 = tkinter.Button(main, text = "Exit", command = ex)
```

So, I don't have any idea to fix it.

Comment: Enable debug. What output do you get?

Comment: After third Read:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programy\Python 3.4.0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Piotrek\Desktop\Python_Emotiv\StnezatorEnglish.py", line 13, in read
    tts.save(soundfile)
  File "D:\Programy\Python 3.4.0\lib\site-packages\gtts-1.1.4-py3.4.egg\gtts\tts.py", line 93, in save
    with open(savefile, 'wb') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/01_Pulpit/syntezator.mp3'

Comment: I have the same problem like @user45193: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809050/how-to-free-resource-in-pygame-mixer)

Answer (score 6):

```
from gtts import gTTS
import playsound
import os

x = ['sunny', 'sagar', 'akhil']
tts = 'tts'
for i in range(0,3):
    tts = gTTS(text= x[i], lang = 'en')
    file1 = str("hello" + str(i) + ".mp3")
    tts.save(file1)
    playsound.playsound(file1,True)
    os.remove(file1)
```

rename the file for every new save, that worked for me.